# After experimentation, how do we learn a final model for deployment?

Tags: predictive-modeling, deployment

I have a question regarding learning a "final" model for deployment. Assuming my task is a classification one, my workflow during experimentation is as follows.

1. Get the data: `X, y`
2. Split the data: `X_tr, y_tr` (training), `X_tu, y_tu` (tuning) and `X_te, y_te` (testing)
3. Learn the model `M` and hyperparameters `H` on `X_tr, y_tr` and `X_tu, y_tu`
4. Validate the performance `P` using `M` on `X_te, y_te`

Assuming my experimental performance is great, now I am ready to deploy the model. What do I do at this point? Here is what I have thought of.

1. Learn a new model `M_p` on all the data `X, y` using the hyperparameters `H` from experimentation. Simply deploy `M_p`.
2. Learn a new model `M_p` and hyperparameters `H_p` using `X, y`.

Answer (score 2):

If you followed the procedure as described, you can just take the tuned model that performs reasonably well on X_te, y_te. You want a model with good performance that generalizes well regarding unknown data. **The assumption here is, that the data in every set is representative for the entirety of available data (and hopefully future data in production), i.e. the data distribution is the same.**

The difficult part will be to regularly update your model given your production data [distribution] changes over time and becomes too dissimilar to your previous training data (see [Concept Drift](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_Drift#:%7E:text=Concept%20Drift%20oder%20data%20drift,Laufe%20der%20Zeit%20unvorhergesehen%20%C3%A4ndern.)).